# Number of rainy days probability distribution in a two-state markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I am working on a Markov Chain model with two states, sunny and rainy.

The transition matrix represents the probabilities of transitioning from sunny to rainy (J) and staying in the rainy state (R) :

\begin{bmatrix}
  1-J & J \\
  1-R & R
\end{bmatrix}

I'm assuming that I start from a sunny state, so my initial-state vector is :

\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

I'm trying to find the probability that the number of rainy days in a year (365 days) is equal to k for any k.

```
P(Number of Rainy Days = k) = ?
```

I tried finding the stationary distribution and then applying Bernoulli's formula, but I'm interested in calculating this probability distribution before equilibrium, hopefully through finding a closed formula.

I appreciate your insights.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that simulating this process is straight forward (that's one of the best things about this kind of process), so you can certainly get a numerical result without much fuss.  Getting closed form solutions might be a challenge.

Comment: I think you need to specify the initial probability distribution (over sunny and rainy).

Comment: @lulu I'm not interested in the numerical result. I'm more interested in the formula of the distribution. All my attempts have lead to nothing so I have nothing to show for it, but I'll take any insights.

Comment: @900edges I did, any thoughts ?

Comment: You should be interested in the numerical result...that's what matters for short term behavior. In any case, having detailed numerical results lets you check whatever recursive scheme, or whatever else, you have.  But, if you only care about exact results, I suggest working it for smaller numbers of days and extend that recursively.

Comment: @lulu I need the formula to generalize something. The problem is that I don't seem to find one. I'll keep trying but your answers don't answer my questions. Thanks anyway.